# Passing and Getting Hexadecimal output from CRC c function to erlang using Port

Tags: c, erlang, port, crc

I have the CRC Error Code generation Logic built in C language, and would like to implement it into the Erlang or use the C function with the Port or the NIF function to get the desired output.

I have c program that works fine, but for some reason I am not being able to integrate this function with the erlang.

I am kind of new to erlang, please help.
Thanks.

**Update**

Followed this link
http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_port.html

```
/* complex.c */

int foo(int x) {
  return x+1;
}

int bar(int y) {
  return y*2;
}
```

The above functions works fine.

But I need to implement the function,
Check_Data_CRC_Information(source, lenth);
where,
 source - Array of Hex values.
 length - integer length of the source array.

I am not being able to send the required values into the Proper format to the Check_Data_CRC_Information function.

Comment: How are you integrating this with Erlang? Or in what way do you want to integrate this?

Comment: When you say "for some reason" you're not able to integrate this with Erlang, you need to be more specific. What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using the Erlang C Ports to communicate with the C Program, as per the link erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_port.html. Both the foo and bar examples works fine. Updated the answer as per the request.